# Set vertical RecyclerView height to correspond to only N items height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Each row in my `RecyclerView` is a single-row `TextView` with a certain size.

I'm looking for a general implementation such that the `RecyclerView`'s height is set to correspond to the height of N such rows.

At the moment I'm using a magic value corresponding to `3 * rowHeight` but it wouldn't be valid if I would change the text size of `TextView`.

Is this possible?

Edit: all rows have the same height

Comment: Are all items the same height? Manually inflate a view holder, measure its height, multiply that by 3, then set it on the ReyclerView by changing the layout params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution given in the comment.
Inflating the row view and then changing the layout params.

```
fun calculateRowHeight(layoutInflater : LayoutInflater, large: Boolean = true): Float {
    val textView = layoutInflater
        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, null) as TextView
    val fm = textView.paint.fontMetrics
    return fm.descent - fm.ascent
}
```

```
recyclerView.apply {
            ...
            layoutParams.height = N * rowHeight.toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your itemView a LinearLayout which have vertical orientation. Then give it's width and height programmatically in your viewHolder like this.You have to calculate each rows width and height.

```
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = your_height;
params.width = your_width;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

However if you have only 2,3 or 4 different heights, I mean these are specific for your recyclerView, you have to use getItemViewType() and make your different layouts and different ViewHolders for each type.

Comment: All rows have identical heights. A row is a TextView with width = wrap_content. I change the row's dimension by modifying the textSize(in sp) property.